# Deleting a document from firestore without name of collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an android app where users can store pdfs in folders. I'm using Firebase Storage for storing PDFs and Firestore for storing the urls and their names. I'm facing a problem in deleting the Firestore data.
Currently here's my data structure:

```
FolderName
    |
    |---PDFname--URL
               --Name
```

Basically FolderName is the collection. So I'm having multiple collections. In each collection/folder there are multiple PDFs. The multiple PDF details of a particular folder are stored as documents. Each document has fields : URL,name.

Now I want the user to be able to delete a particular PDF of a particular Folder. When he has clicked on a folder, he can see all the PDFs. He long presses a PDF to delete it. But now I don't know the collection/folder to which it belongs. Is it possible to delete a document if I know its uid but not the collection?

Or is there a better way to structure my data?

**Edit**: Here is a screenshot of my firestore data-

[image]

1,2,3,4 etc are the folders. Folder 3 is containing a PDF which I want to delete. This folder/collection may contain more than one PDF.

Comment: So you have multiple collections as `FolderName`? Besides that, instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it and indicate the exact data you want to delete.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the screenshot, Thanks

Comment: *Folder 3 is containing a PDF which I want to delete.* You want to delete the document named `Resources.pdf` only from "folder" 3? *This folder/collection may contain more than one PDF.* So there may be more documents, you want to delete all of them? Or you want to delete documents from multiple collections at once? Please respond to all these questions?

Comment: I will be deleting only one PDF from one folder at a time. So Resources.pdf will only be deleted from folder 3 (or the collection). If this folder has more than one pdf, I will only be deleting one of them at a time. Although I can delete all of them, if I individually delete all of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation regaring the [delete operation in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data), the way you can remove a document is as follows:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference collRef = rootRef.collection("3");
DocumentReference pdfRef = collRef.document("Resources.pdf");
pdfRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Resources.pdf successfully deleted!");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.w("TAG", "Error deleting document", e);
    }
});
```

This code will permanently remove the `Resources.pdf` document from collection `3`. If you need to delete another document within the same collection, you should change the `pdfRef` above to:

```
DocumentReference pdfRef = collRef.document("AnotherResources.pdf");
```

And if you want to delete a PDF from another collection, for example from `2` collection, simply use:

```
CollectionReference collRef = rootRef.collection("2");
DocumentReference pdfRef = collRef.document("ResourcesName.pdf");
```

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo but my problem is , I don't know the name of the collection. For displaying the PDFs , I have an activity containing a recyclerview and a custom adapter class. I can access the folderName within the activity but not the recyclerAdapter. So that's why I was asking if we could delete a document using it's uid if we don't know the collection name,or if somehow I can access the folderName string from my recyclerAdapter class where I'm actually deleting the documents.

Comment: If you don't know the collection name, then there is no way you can delete that document. The name of the collection is mandatory to be added in your reference. You cannot delete something without knowing at least the name of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to delete a document if I know its uid but not the collection?

No, it's not possible.  You must be able to construct a full path to a document in order to delete it.

It's not a good idea to name collections with dynamic data.  The names of collections should be **static**, and always well-known by your code, so that you can use them to perform queries.

Consider instead putting all dynamic data in documents, so they can be found by queries on your statically named collections.  It's not clear to me what exactly you should do instead, but you should definitely create for yourself a way to find documents based on the inputs you have available.  This normally involves creating properties in your documents that you can use to query.

Note also that Firestore is not organized like a computer filesystem.  Collections are not at all the same as folders.  They are just containers for documents, and you should design your data so that you can query to find documents using collections.